# Why can't I see my file in RAM?

Tags: linux, memory

In nano, I created a simple text file named 'blue_pink_red_orange_green' with the following contents:

> red blue orange green pink

I then opened the file again and did:

```
sudo strings /dev/mem | grep orange
```

but nothing was found. However, using `sudo strings /dev/mem` outputs a large amount of data.

I'm not using any swap, so why can't I find my text file in my memory? Is it really in there somewhere? If so, how can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into trouble because `/dev/mem` has holes in it: memory locations that don't exist can't be read.

`strings` is designed to read a regular file (or pipe or other input stream) from beginning to end and assumes there can't be holes in its input. It probably aborts the first time it gets a read error, which would correspond to the first hole in `/dev/mem`. That means it would never read anything beyond the first hole.